# Android keyboard is covering Qml TextField

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have a `Dialog` containing a header, footer, and content item which is a `ListView`:

```
Dialog {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    x: 10
    y: 100

    header: Rectangle {
        
    }

    contentItem: ListView {
        delegate: TextField {
            // this is covered by the Android keyboard
        }
    }

    footer: Rectangle {

    }
}
```

On iOS the whole screen is shifted up so that the ListView's `TextField` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-textfield.html) owning the text cursor is always visible. On Android the `TextField`'s cursor is covered by the Android keyboard. I already tried to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` but without success.

Is there an easy way to make sure that the `TextField` currently owning the cursor is always visible? Or is the only solution to manually move the Dialog's y coordinate?

Qml with hidden keyboard:
[image: Qml with hidden keyboard]

Qml keyboard hidding cursor:
[image: Qml keyboard hidding cursor]

Regular Android text field:
[image: Regular Android text field]

Regular Android text field is shifted up when the keyboard is open:
[image: Regular Android text field is shifted up when the keyboard is open]

Regards,

Comment: It seems to be a bug, I have created an [issue in bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-100436)

Answer (score 2):

The entire text view?  No, that's not how keyboards work in Android.  The only lever you have is the softInputMode, which is either pan or resize.  In pan mode, the screen is scrolled up such that the cursor is always visible (but the rest of the text view may not be).  In resize mode, the app is resized in the space above the keyboard, and then if needed shifted so the cursor is visible.  This can sometimes make more of the screen visible, if you had empty space on screen and your layout is set to scale well (login screens frequently benefit).  But there is no way to ensure the entire text view, or any other field, is still on screen.  It's just not how Android works.

Comment: It is sufficient that the cursor is visible (i.e. not covered by the keyboard). But I cannot get this working with the Qml ``TextField``.

Comment: What are you seeign then?  Is the screen not moving at all?  That would sound like "adjustNone" mode, which does exist although using it is very rare.  Its worth checking to make sure at runtime that the softInputMode is what it should be.  But there's nothing you can do other than that.  There's not even a way to know when the keyboard is launched and dismissed reliably.

Comment: I have added some screenshots showing: Qml with closed keyboard, Qml with keyboard covering text field compared with the regular Android control which correctly shifts the field so that it stays visible.

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml tweak: `<activity ... android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"...` fixed this for me (tested on Qt 5.12 & 5.15 with a QML ui)